# Graphical Layout on Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

In the Graphical Layout in Eclipse, I am trying to find the view and layout sidebars as shown in the snapshot below I took of a pdf. I don't know how to view it, I gave up looking. I am asking for  clear instruction on how to get them on Eclipse Indigo.
[image]

What I have atm is Palette, as shown below, and I don't need.
[image]

Comment: Ummm...you have a layouts and different views tabs right there on the left. I don't understand the problem. Also, you are a lot better off if you use the xml tab to do your layouts and use the graphical view for maybe checking what they look like once you build them.

Comment: None of the collapsed tabs on the side have what you're looking for? It looks like layouts is there and one of the others is probably equivalent to views.

Comment: In that version, the views are under different tabs depending on what type of view they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is a different version, the ADT version that you are using is newer all what you need is still there but maybe in different tab, just look for the widget you need not the tab,
and don't be lazy my friend, you have much to do ;)